# Swagger auto generated file issue with _observableOf(null) in angular 12?

Tags: angular, swagger, nswag, angular12

So i'm using swagger and Nswag for a very long time, I can see the auto generated methods used to generate a line like this to exit as default value:

```
return _observableOf<MyClassData>(<any>null);
```

...And now with the same nswag json file, it generates this way:

```
return _observableOf(null);
```

Which seems to be valid for Angular 9 because it did not support strict=true, but now with my Angular 11/12 projects, this throws an error that says:

> error TS2322: Type 'Observable' is not assignable to type
> 'Observable'.   Type 'null' is not assignable to type
> 'MyClassData'.

Solution 1)
Manually replace the auto generated file by adding: **return _observableOf < MyClassData >(< any > null);** which is crazy because everytime I generate the file, I will lose the changes.

Solution 2)
Open/edit the angular.json, in the schematics/angular:application, strict: change it from true to false, of course it stops failing, but I would very prefeer to keep the code as strict.

What could be the best solution here?
Is there a way to specify to NSWAG that should keep returning as it was doing it in the past?

Thanks.

Comment: Nswag is a library right? If so, you should open an issue on their GitHub to ask for proper compatibility with strict mode of Typescript.

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar issue with my project. I upgraded most of my packages, including **Angular** to v12 and **rxjs** to v7.

The nswag-generated file also gave me a compile error saying the _observableOf was depricated and that:

> Type 'Observable<*object*>' is not assignable to type
> 'Observable<*object*[]>'

for all endpoints that returned arrays.

I think this is because nswag is not compatible with rxjs 7+ (yet). **It worked for me to downgrade the rxjs to 6.6.7.**

Answer (score 1):

It seems it is solved for RXJS Verison 7. After updating `ngswag` version my problem like yours was solved. Also, I changed my rxjs and typescript versions inside .nswag file.  `"rxJsVersion": 7.5, and "typeScriptVersion": 4.7`

> Issue Solved Here
> https://github.com/RicoSuter/NSwag/issues/3463